# "rsInternalError" after installing local SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I installed SSRS locally on my PC and set the connection to my work database. After installation reporting server, the page shows an error something like the found version is 'N'. The expected version is '163'. I deleted all rows in ServerUpgradeHistory and DBUpgradeHistory above '163'.

After that I restarted Reporting Services. And now I have another error:

> An internal error occurred on the report server.
> See the error log for more details. (rsInternalError)
> For more information about this error navigate to the report server
> on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

In log file I see the error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

I don't know how to fix it and our database has no backup copies.

Comment: Did you take backups of the report server database before modifying them? Because you're probably going to have to restore from them. The `ServerUpgradeHistory` and `DBUpgradeHistory` tables only keep records of which modifications have been applied to the report server service and database (respectively). By just deleting the more recent records from the `DBUpgradeHistory` table the actual schema changes from versions above 163 will still be applied to the database and future attempts to apply the upgrade(s) again will fail.

Comment: Are you sure it was complaining about version `163`? That would date the database to around SQL Server 2014 vintage and you've tagged `ssrs-2017`.

Comment: I installed 2017 version locally on my pc. Report service complaining about version 163!
And yes, we have no backups.